# LSTM layer building getting warning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-layer

WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 3, 1) for input Tensor("lstm_3_input:0", shape=(None, 3, 1), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (32, 2, 1).

I am working in 3 sensor data where I want to take temperature and light values from the dataset as features/predictors and humidity values as a target.
Can anyone help me explain this error

Comment: Your Model expected shape `(None, 3, 1)` but received an input of shape `(32, 2, 1)`.

Comment: How to rectify it

Comment: Provide the right input shape

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share the sample code? so that i can help you better. Thanks!